# Is there a shortcut for "create or modify" d3 axis (transition with modified data/size)?

Tags: d3.js

My D3 visualizations have transitions when data changes or when resizing the window. The x and y axis do transitions as well, but I always have some code which hasn't got the typical short D3-style:

Example (the first code block is not important and is visible here only for understanding):

```
var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]);
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .ticks(20)
    .orient('bottom');

var svg = d3.select(containerSelector).select('svg');
if (svg.empty()) {
    svg = d3.select(containerSelector).append('svg');
    svg.append('g');
}
var group = svg
    .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .select('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');
```

Now this is **the code I'd like to optimize**:

```
var xAxisSvg = group.select('.x.axis');
if (xAxisSvg.empty()) {
    group.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'x axis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
        .call(xAxis);
} else {
    xAxisSvg.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
        .call(xAxis);
}
```

Is there a similar way like `enter()` to create the axis-svg and apply a new logical axis? How can this repeating code be optimized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it a lot shorter by doing only the bare minimum necessary to make it run:

```
var xAxisSvg = group.select('.x.axis');
if (xAxisSvg.empty()) {
  xAxisSvg = group.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'x axis');
}
xAxisSvg.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
    .call(xAxis);
```

Alternatively, you could bind some dummy data to it and use the enter/update pattern, although I wouldn't consider that particularly good design in this case.

```
var xAxisSvg = group.selectAll('.x.axis').data([0]);
xAxisSvg.enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'x axis');
xAxisSvg.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
    .call(xAxis);
```

Comment: First option works. Second came into my mind as well, but it needs a comment to be understood by other developers. Thanks!